# IE and jQuery Masonry do not agree, (cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-masonry

I have this site that is built using the jQuery Masonry plugin, the site works great in Firefox and Chrome, however on first run on IE9 the layout is broken and it seems Masonry is not being loaded.

This is the error that is output into the console of IE9.

> cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'appended'

Here is a link to the staging site: http://rw.freelanc3r.co.uk/ please view in Chrome or Firefox before IE to see the desired outcome.

I understand there are no images on the page, please ignore this minor defect.

Comment: There are no other errors showing in the console in IE9?

Comment: [Answer for prior to initializtion][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068935/cannot-call-methods-on-masonry-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-call-destr

This link may help you.. Kindly Look over it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there may be a problem with the fact that the Masonry initializing code is placed inside the `imagesLoaded` callback and none of your images are actually loading. FF, Chrome, and IE9 may have different behavior regarding how they handle this situation.

Does the problem still happen when the page has loading images?

Comment: Thanks Rob, that fixed the error it was looking for images and breaking on that point. Greatly appreciated for your help